# Ruby: convert string to array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

```
a = IO.readlines('uniqID.txt')
puts id = a[0]
id = ["Gh089k" , "HG987"] #getting value from txt file 
id.class #String
id.push("GD977")
```

How to convert the above string into array. so that I use method like push. Here id is string looks like an array

```
Error: undefined method `push' for "[\"Gh089k\", \"HG987\"]":String (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Could you check the code example? `id` should have `Array` type: [23] `pry(main)> id = ["Gh089k" , "HG987"] 
=> ["Gh089k", "HG987"]
[25] pry(main)> id.class
=> Array`

Comment: @mrzasa id type is string.`id.class` gives string as output

Comment: can you put the first line of your uniqID.txt file? Seems like it is `"[\"Gh089k\", \"HG987\"]"` so when ruby reads it, it is just a string...

Comment: please, just run `id = ["Gh089k" , "HG987"];  id.class` in a console

Comment: @mrzasa id = ["Gh089k" , "HG987"]; This gives an type Array. but when I read from txt, It act as type string

Comment: @compsy in your example code, you assign `["Gh089k" , "HG987"]` to `id`, thus overwriting any previous value. `id.class` is therefore `Array`, not `String`. If you wanted to show something else, you should edit your example accordingly (maybe provide two examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a JSON string. You can parse json string to get the desired result.

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse("[\"Gh089k\", \"HG987\"]") # => ["Gh089k", "HG987"]
```

Here:

```
id = JSON.parse(a[0])
```

Hope it helps !